# Windows 10 wifi network is not discovering

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, wifi-driver

My windows 10 laptop is not showing wifi devices any more. I believe that I corrupted Network Adapter drivers anyhow. Now my question is if I reset my pc by selecting "Keep my data" option will it restore my wifi network related issue? I Know that restoring pc with "keep my data" option checked, it will remove all third party programs and will not remove any personal file. Now, my question is ,will " reset " option (while keep my data option is checked) fix my wifi devices not showing problem? And delete all present drivers and reinstall default drivers ? And if you have any solution that will fix this wifi related thing please help me.

[Problem screenshot](https://ibb.co/ZKB3PVv)

Comment: I think restoring your system should be a last attempt as it takes a while and reset many settings. Have you tried [re-installing the driver](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-you-uninstall-and-reinstall-drivers-in/a806bd04-3698-4a47-8149-2bfea53a3539) for the network adapter?

Comment: Try removing and re-installing the Network Drivers (it was not clear if you did this). Reinstalling network drivers reset them and TCP/IP components related to them and may fix your issue.

Comment: I tried to reinstall them and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the network adapter drivers (they were still showing an error sign). Then I've booted into reset mode but didn't restore the pc. I just entered there and restarted the pc. Voila! Solved my problem!